# Three year old with good speech, now sometimes making up own words, especially names.

Tags: development, language

I think he is just exploring rhythms and sounds but would like to learn more. My other theory is that it just gives great satisfaction to be able to  appear authoritative when he doesn't have a full answer, as he frequently rattles off beautifully rhythmic made up names in circumstances when he doesn't know the correct ones (eg talking about other children at the playground).

Any assistance in understanding or pointing to further information sources would be gratefully received.  Its quite lovely, so I am not concerned, simply curious.

Comment: I don't have details so I'll just comment - our now 4-year-old still makes up words, though it seems he recognizes it as playing with words/sounds as he usually giggles and later says he's being silly

Comment: I'd also see it as a good sign (our older son, now 5, is also often playing with words and seems to be quite talented when it comes to learning languages) and I'd be interested in further information.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like Jargoning. It's a normal developmental language milestone for kids as young as 12 to 18 months. Many kids continue to do it for years, and they develop normal expressive and receptive speech patterns over time. Here's a [site where more people share their experiences](http://www.mothering.com/community/t/484035/jargoning-speech).

Some kids make up their own words and even their own languages around that age as they explore how language, syntax, and prosidy work. Searching for "jargoning" and "prosody" may help you learn more.